# Ubuntu one is not working?

Tags: ubuntu-one

In large RED text : "The information could not be retrieved. Maybe your internet connection is down?" on the ubuntu one control panel. I am currently connected.

Below is what I've got from u1sdtool --status :

State: LOCAL_RESCAN
    connection: With User With Network
    description: doing local rescan
    is_connected: False
    is_error: False
    is_online: False
    queues: WORKING

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have proxy set on your browser, but not on u1?

Comment: I suspect a bug. I have had a few problems over the last few days with u1.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it is a bug. To report a bug press Alt+F2 and type `ubuntu-bug ubuntuone`
You will need to register in launchpad to report.

In the mean time I might try `sudo rm -rf ~/.ubuntuone`

This will remove the user file which may be corrupt then restart ubuntuone.